# How to get "Printed" versions of IEEE Transactions (Software Engineering) monthly journals?

Tags: journals, ieee

I want to subscribe to the monthly Volumes of **[IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering](https://www.computer.org/csdl/journal/ts)** monthly volumes in Printed form.

I tried to gather information about the subscription cost and visited the official website. As shown in the screenshot below, the subscription price is 129 USD in Germany (+135 USD for unlimited access to IEEE CS digital).

**QUESTION:** I don't find any information if am I going to get Printed journals or not. If not, where can I choose the option to get them? And, is the price monthly or annual?

[image]

After pressing the "Get Started" button on the right side, I get the following screen:

[image]

Comment: If you click on "get started", you'll likely found out, at least, whether the price is monthly or annual. When I want to find hidden pieces of information about a subscription, I usually follow the process until they ask me the credit card number.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: Tried that, but it does not say anything about being monthly or annual. I assume it to be annual because (129 + 135 = $264) would be a lot for a monthly DIGITAL subscription. Updated new screenshot.

Comment: That might be monthly. Here's the [2023 non-members subscription price list](https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/pubs/productmarketing/subscription-price-list-web.pdf). T-SE is online only with a yearly subscription price of USD2520.

Comment: @mkennedy: oh, that's so expensive for me then. But they really have several prices mentioned on different pages. On another page of IEEE, the membership price is $339. So confusing!